# How to solve the 'could not find or load main class robocode.robocode' error?

Tags: java, eclipse, robocode

I am now a starter in Robocode and now I am trying to run my first robot from Eclipse. I have followed the tutorial on [Robocodewiki](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/Eclipse/Running_from_Eclipse) but the Eclipse keep reporting `Error: Could not find or load main class robocode.Robocode
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: robocode.Robocode`

Here is my first robot code:

```
package robots;
import robocode.*;
//import robocode.Robocode;
//import robocode.ScannedRobotEvent;

public class Robot1 extends Robot {
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        ahead(100);
        turnGunRight(360);
        back(100);
        turnGunRight(360);
    }
}

public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
    fire(1);
}
```

}

This project is stored at `E:\Java Pojects\MyRobot` while my robocode was installed at `C:\robocode`
Also the JRE library `JavaSE-11(jdk-11.0.1)` and robocode version`1.9.3.7`

Appreciate if anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved:
When you import the external .jar file you should add it to your projects' classpath rather than the module path then this problem will be solved.